# Bundle and load objects to be randomly read in an iOS app

Tags: ios, json

I want to bundle JSON objects, each keyed by a unique int, so that my app can randomly deserialize X of them at any given point. I see two ways to do this without touching core data (please tell me if there's more):

1) Bundle a single JSON file which stores all the objects, deserialize the file during startup into some collection, and randomly deserialize X objects

2) Bundle each object in a separate file named by its unique int, fetch random X files and deserialize the object

Which approach is better? Is there a limit on how many files an iOS app can store? If the approach is dependent on the number of strings the app has to store, please say at which point is better to do one approach over the other.

Comment: Either separate files or a database would be much better than one large single file that needs to be read into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to favour the multiple files approach, although it does depend a little on how large the files (and total amount of data) are.  Either way the data is going to be included in your app bundle - so the app distribution size will be the same.

Using individual files will use less RAM while your app is running, at the expense of some processor time to read in the files.  If you need to frequently change the files you are using (once per second or less) then a single file in memory may be better.

There is a limit on the number of files you can store in the file system, but unless you are talking about millions it probably won't be an issue.