# What is the limit of number of resource files on an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I plan on bundling a number of JSON files in my app. I'd like to know if there's a limit on number of resource files on an iOS app.

Comment: Yes, 2GB (or is it 4GB) is the max size of an iOS app (the ipa file). Unless you have *REALLY* large JSON files, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @maddy I want to know if there's any restriction on number of files rather than the size of files.

Comment: There is no limit on count, just size. I have an app with over 1500 files in the app bundle. How many are you talking about?

Comment: For the prototype maybe less than 5,000. The problem I'm trying to solve is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027985/bundle-and-load-objects-to-be-randomly-read-in-an-ios-app. Appreciate your feedback if you have better alternatives.

Comment: @rmaddy So is there no limit on the number of files?

Comment: See my 2nd comment. In reality, the filesystem only allows 2.1 billion files per folder so be careful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on the files, as the functions to look up resources simply ask the file system API  to look up the item in the app's directory. And that file system is using the HFS+ format, which has no practical limit on the files that it can manage inside a single directory. HFS Standard (the older format before HFS+) had a limit of 64k files per dir, IIRC, but the limit for HFS+ is 2^31, which is practically unlimited.

To add to your related question: One drawback of having 1000s of files in a dir is that it might take a while to create them all, meaning that the installation of your app may take longer than if you had the data all contained in a single file. The most effective way might be to use a container file, e.g. a zip (without compression), for which exist several iOS/ObjC libs.